# How to redirect paypal native android sdk to open payment sheet for custom return url?

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented paypal native sdk in an android application. Paypal recommended to use the application id with postfix "://paypal" as return url. But the problem is my application id contains (_) underscore which is counted invalid as return url by paypal. So i used another custom id and deep linked that to the checkout activity. So when i try to pay it takes me back to the checkout page after logging to account and sent some data through intent (i.e return_url?code=value&scope=value) but it doesn't open up the card selection bottom sheet for payment which is expected. I created another test project which doesn't contain underscore in application id and the payment works as expected (it does show the card selection bottom sheet after coming back to checkout activity along with granting the account permissions).

Comment: "I created another test project which doesn't contain underscore in application id" -- seems you found the answer

Comment: My app is on production and its not possible to alter the application id.

Comment: @Habib Hello my friend, did you find solution?

Comment: You can choose a custom url for PayPal checkout and here is the documentation of it: https://developer.paypal.com/limited-release/native-checkout/android/customize-return-url/

Answer (score 1):

I opened an issue in their android checkout repository and they created a documentation about how to choose a custom URL if your app id contains an underscore or special character.

Here is the link of the documentation:
https://developer.paypal.com/limited-release/native-checkout/android/customize-return-url/